# How can contentEquals compare multiple strings with all strings matching?

Tags: java, if-statement, equals, do-while

Good morning,
The following java code shall compare three strings with requiredProgram and only execute the if-loop and the do-while-loop if requiredProgram does not equal **all three** strings. It is instead executing the if-loop and the do-while-loop if only one or two of the strings don't match the requiredProgram. How can I program the code to do what I want it to do?

```
if (!requiredProgram.contentEquals(program1)||
    !requiredProgram.contentEquals(program2)||
    !requiredProgram.contentEquals(program3)) {
        System.out.println("Ohje, das tut mir leid. Hier muss ein Fehler unterlaufen sein! Bitte versuchen sie es erneut.");

    }
    } while(!requiredProgram.contentEquals(program1)||
            !requiredProgram.contentEquals(program2)||
            !requiredProgram.contentEquals(program3));
```

Comment: Java !== JavaScript

Comment: You need to change `||` to `&&`

Comment: Please don't add things like _(solved)_ to a question title. Accepting an answer is the way to indicate that a question was solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you the 3 `program` to be different of `requiredProgram` you may write this like one these equivalent boolean expression :

- Should be different of the 3 program: *different of P1* **AND** *different of P2* **AND** *different of P3*

  ```
  if(!requiredProgram.contentEquals(program1) &&
     !requiredProgram.contentEquals(program2) &&
     !requiredProgram.contentEquals(program3))
  ```
- Shouldn't be equal to any of the 3: **NOT** (*equals to P1* **OR** *equals to P2* **OR** *equals to P3*)

  ```
  if(!(requiredProgram.contentEquals(program1) || 
       requiredProgram.contentEquals(program2) || 
       requiredProgram.contentEquals(program3)))
  ```

Answer (score 1):

On first sight of that logic expression, one has either of both:

```
case1 or case2 or case3                     case1 || case2 || case3
not case1 and not case2 and not case3       !case1 && !case2 && !case3
```

So seeing

```
!case1 || !case2 || !case3
```

one in 99.9% of the occurrences may say: wrong.
At least one term is true, hence the expression is true.

You can abbreviate the code as:

```
if (!Set.of(program1, program2, program3).contains(requiredProgram)) {
```

Older java, less efficient & meaningful:

```
if (!Arrays.asList(program1, program2, program3).contains(requiredProgram)) {
```